# How does Treemap works?

Tags: java, excel, treemap

So I'm trying to read data from an excel file and I use Treemap to read the file. But the problem is that treemap puts my data random into its list. Although, I set an index when I use it.

```
//This writes the data from an old file
//writer is my treemap
//sReadData is a List with the old data

for (int i = 0; i < (sReadData.size()+1)/5; i++) {
                
     writer.put(String.valueOf(i),new Object[] { sReadData.get(i*5),sReadData.get(i*5+1),sReadData.get(i*5+2),sReadData.get(i*5+3),sReadData.get(i*5+4)});
}
            

writer.put(String.valueOf(iCounter +1), new Object[] { "Name", "Date","Time", "Type","Owner"});

//This writes the new data
for (int i = 0; i < sName.length; i++) {
                              //iCounter is just the number of rows from the old file|These are just some Array with some data
     writer.put(String.valueOf(iCounter+2+i), new Object[] { sName[i], sDate[i],sTime[i], sTypes[i],sOwners[i]});
}
```

My mistake was that I initialized my treemap wrong. It should be like this: Map<Integer, Object[]> tMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Object[]>();

Comment: Are you sure you want a `String` key where you could have an `Integer` or `Long` key instead? A `TreeMap` is a `SortableMap` sorted by key automatically and `String`s get sorted differently... By the way, how does the initialization of your `writer` look? That name is bad for a data structure that does not write anything anyway.

Comment: Using `writer` as a variable name for a `Map` is counter-intuitive.

Comment: Map<String, Object[]> writer = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>(); this is how I initialized it and when I try to use an int, I'll get an error

Comment: And I will change the name of the variable.

Comment: A `TreeMap` is sorted by key, and strings are sorted lexicographically, e.g. `"10"` is sorted before `"2"`, so that's what the map does, exactly as it should. The problem is that your map shouldn't be keyed by a string value, but by a number, so `10` is sorted after `2`.

Comment: Okay that explains my error, but when I try to use an int instead of a String, i'll will this error: The method put(String, Object[]) in the type Map<String,Object[]> is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object[])

Comment: Nevermind I found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order won't be random.  But it may not be what you expect.  Strings are ordered lexically, so that "1" < "10" < "100" < ... < "11" ... < "2".

If you want the `TreeMap` entries to be returned in numerical order, use `Integer` as the key type.

---

> When I try to use an `int` instead of a `String`, I get this error:
>
> ```
>  The method put(String, Object[]) in the type Map<String,Object[]>
>  is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object[])
> ```

You also need to change the **declaration** of the map to `TreeMap<Integer, Object[]>`.